# CSS difference on mac and windows

Tags: html, css, windows, macos

I have some CSS applied to a few divs. It looks all good on windows, but it behaves differently on Mac on the event of mouse over.

The behavior can be seen [here](http://codepen.io/shaonline/pen/adMJQM). If you could manage opening it on Mac and on Windows you will notice the difference.

I would appreciate if some can tell me how can i make it behave similar as it behaves on windows. Again, i want it to behave as it behaves on Windows.

I will show my code here as well.

The html

```
<div class="goal" >
<div class="top-layer" >
    <div class="component">
        <select class="component-select">
            <option value="">select me </option>
          <option value="">option one</option>
          <option value="">option two</option>
          <option value="">option three</option>              
        </select>
        <span id="width_tmp"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="period" >
      <select class="period-select">
            <option value="">something</option>                
        </select>
        <span id="width_tmp"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="close clickable" >X</div>
</div>
```

and the CSS,

```
.noselect, .clickable {
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
 }
.clickable {
cursor: pointer;
/*border: 1px solid transparent;*/
 }
.clickable:hover {
/*border: 1px solid #4D7994;*/
background: #3f6379;  
}
[contenteditable="true"].single-line {
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
margin-bottom: -7px;
height: 12px;
max-width: 60px;
}
[contenteditable="true"].single-line br {
display:none;

}
[contenteditable="true"].single-line * {
display:inline;
white-space:nowrap;
}
.goal {
position: relative;
background: #5A8EAE;
width: 364px;
height: auto;
color: #F4F7F9;
float: left;
margin-right: 14px;
margin-bottom: 14px;
font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.goal span[contenteditable=true] {
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid #5A8EAE;
padding-left: 2px;
}
.goal span[contenteditable=true]:focus {
background-color: white;
color: black;
border: 1px solid #5A8EAE;
min-width: 10px;
}
.top-layer{
width: 100%;
height: 33px;
float: left;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;;
}
.component{
float: left;
width: 63%;
padding: 2.5% 3% 3% 2%;    
}
.period{
float: left;
padding-top: 10px;    
}
.close{
float: right;
padding: 2.8%;
border-left: 1px solid #9FBDCF;
}
select.period-select {
border: 0 !important;  /*Removes border*/
-webkit-appearance: none;  /*Removes default chrome and safari style*/
-moz-appearance: none; /* Removes Default Firefox style*/
/*background: #0088cc url(img/select-arrow.png) no-repeat 90% center;*/
text-indent: 0.01px; /* Removes default arrow from firefox*/
text-overflow: "";  /*Removes default arrow from firefox*/ /*My custom style      for fonts*/
border-radius: 2px;
background-color: #5A8EAE;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
width:auto;
direction: ltr;
float: right;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 3px 0;
margin-top: -6px;
}
select.period-select:hover, select.component-select:hover {
-webkit-appearance: menulist;
background-color: #3f6379;
color: white;    
}
select.component-select  {
border: 0 !important;  /*Removes border*/
-webkit-appearance: none;  /*Removes default chrome and safari style*/
-moz-appearance: none; /* Removes Default Firefox style*/
/*background: #0088cc url(img/select-arrow.png) no-repeat 90% center;*/
text-indent: 0.01px; /* Removes default arrow from firefox*/
text-overflow: "";  /*Removes default arrow from firefox*/ /*My custom style for fonts*/
color: #FFF;
background-color: #5A8EAE;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
width:240px ;
padding: 3px 0;
margin-top: -6px;
padding-left:0px;
margin-left:0px;  
}
select:hover {
cursor: pointer;
/*background: #0088cc url(img/select-arrow.png) no-repeat 90% center;*/
}
```

Comment: Please *specify* the differences...not all of us have both Mac and Windows

Comment: it moves towards right and a bit upward as well. In terms of CSS it takes padding to the left and bottom, which gives the impression of the text moving to right on hovering.

Comment: are you using the same browser on both the mac and the pc?

Comment: Is it different on e.g. *Mac Firefox* and *Windows Firefox* or *Mac Safari* and *Windows IE*?

Comment: yeah its the same chrome on both Windows and Mac.

Comment: on Mac both chrome and Safari give me a different behavior, which is not wanted.

Comment: Its adding -webkit-appearance:menulist on Mac which is creating problem. Why does it move so much? it doesn't move assigning other values but on "menulist"  it moves. why? :(